# jQuery Messy Animation

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation

So I have this animation here http://kevingilbertportfolio.com/help/index.html and I am trying to get it to move smoothly. It is supposed to whenever you mouse over it come out and when u bring the mouse cursor out it goes back in.. as you can see it is very very very messy.

HTML + CSS + jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <style type='text/css'>
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background-color:#636363;
}

.facebook-sw {
    margin-top:120px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:-300px;
    position: relative;
}

.fb-icon {
    float:left;
    margin-right:14px;
}

.fb-like-box {
    float:left;
}

.wrapper {overflow: hidden;}
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.facebook-sw').hover(function() {
        $('.facebook-sw').animate({
            left: '-=300'
        }, 900, function() {
            // Animation complete.

        });
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.facebook-sw').mouseout(function() {
        $('.facebook-sw').animate({
            left: '+=300'
        }, 900, function() {
            // Animation complete.

        });
    });
});
//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="facebook-sw">
            <img class="fb-icon" src="image/fb-icon.PNG" width="110" height="113" alt="">
            <img class="fb-like-box" src="image/example.JPG" height="544" width="292" alt="">
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**HUGE thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (working fiddle can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/c9w3n/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.facebook-sw').hover(
        function() {
            $('.facebook-sw').stop(true, true).animate({
                left: '-=300'
            }, 900, function() { });
        }, function() {
            $('.facebook-sw').stop(true, true).animate({
                left: '+=300'
            }, 900, function() { });
        }
    );
});
```

The `.hover()` method in jQuery takes in two functions in which case the first one is for `mouseover` and the second one is for `mouseout`.

Also, the issue you are having is related to animation queues, every time the mouse moves in or out, the entire animations keep getting added to the element, to prevent this, you can use `.stop()`. You can check the documentation for details, but the two parameters `true, true` that I have passed in basically say that cancel any other animations on that element and if any animation is currently running - move the element immediately to the end of the animation.

**Edit**

To prevent that flickering / snappy behavior you need to change the way you are animating the div. Instead of changing the left or right positioning, you need define an open and a close position for the div and use that.

Working fiddle for the same here: http://jsfiddle.net/c9w3n/7/

Comment: Edited answer, the comment lines were messing up the syntax. Also added the live fiddle.

Comment: But now say you highlight inside it it comes out perfectly and then if u highlight out of it it starts going back in perfectly but what if the user puts his mouse cursor back in it while its going back in it freaks out how would i fix this

Comment: @user1844077 Ok, I have added the new fiddle with the "smoothness" that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use hoverIntent (http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin like so:

```
function mouseOn() {
    $('.facebook-sw').animate({'margin-right' : '0'}, 900);
}

function mouseOff() {
    $('.facebook-sw').animate({'margin-right' : '-300px'}, 900);
}

$('.facebook-sw').hoverIntent(mouseOn, mouseOff);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 $(".facebook-sw").hover(
    function () {
       $(this).animate({
           left: '-=300'
         }, 900, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        });
    }, 
    function () {
       $(this).animate({
          left: '+=300'
        }, 900, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    }
```

);

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
       <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
    <title> Auto hide </title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
    body
    {overflow:hidden;}
    .wrapper
    {position:absolute;right:-300px;}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $('.wrapper').hover(function(){
       $('.wrapper').stop().animate({'right':0},4000);}
       ,function(){$('.wrapper').stop().animate({'right':-300},4000);}
       );
    });
-->
</script>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="facebook-sw">
            <img class="fb-icon" src="http://kevingilbertportfolio.com/help/image/fb-icon.PNG" width="110" height="113" alt="">
            <img class="fb-like-box" src="http://kevingilbertportfolio.com/help/image/example.JPG" height="544" width="292" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i hope work to you ...